# How to repair/play really broken AVI file

Tags: repair, avi, mplayer

A while back I was recording a video on a webcam using an app that saved the file to disk. Unfortunately the file got a little too large for a 32 bit OS to handle and crashed. I was left with an avi file that would not open in any of the common media players such as VLC (opens with --/-- time, no seek bar and no error messages).

I found a player that partially plays the file, called Mplayer (not to be confused with Windows Media Player) that plays the content, so I can see there is readable data there, but there are errors in the file in places which force the video to close - I can skip over them if I know where they are though.

I would like to repair the AVI so that it plays throughout in programs such as VLC, it's OK if the damaged parts are cut out. Anyone know how to do this? I tried Bandifix, RemoRepair, Divx++ and they all give me errors such as 'Not a valid AVI file', etc.

Comment: Have a look at mencoder - which is built off the same libraries as ffmpeg to do transcoding to other formats. (Also try ffmpeg)

Comment: Yeah, I did try mencoder after reading suggestions on these boards here, but it just more than doubles the file size to >8GB and truncates the file. And I can't even play the first good part.

I can play the original file with KMPlayer (with no skip/seek bar) so I might just have a screen capture window running to capture the 5h33m footage.

It's a bit of a stretch though, so any other suggestions gratefully appreciated before I do this.

Comment: If the file is not confidential, make it available and I'll have a play with my tools.

Comment: Thanks for the offer David, but it is rather too large to upload to the web.